# IOS Turn Based Game - Push notifications alerting player that it is their turn?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase, urbanairship.com

I have an IOS, multiplayer turn-based game already made. My goal is to have a player play their turn, and then have a push notification be sent to the other player's device notifying them that it is their turn to play.

I have experimented with Urban Airship and have a sample app there that is capable of broadcasting push notifications to all registered devices, or devices that are manually entered.

Is it possible to trigger an urban airship push notification to only the other player from within my app? I can pull the opponents device token from a Firebase DB if needed.

If this is not possible, can anybody steer me in the correct direction? I've done a fair amount of research, and everything I find points me towards Parse, which is closing down of course.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't send a push from one device to another, instead device A needs to tell a server to send a push to device B.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Firebase, there is a great solution you can use. There is a nice service called Batch. Batch helps sending push notifications and it works great with Firebase. Basically, you can register an user with his Firebase Auth Id into Batch service when he logs in the app and now you can send a notification on his device using his Firebase Auth ID and REST API provided by Batch.

It works great for me. I have a script observing my Firebase data and deciding if there is a need to send any notification. If it is, it uses Batch REST API to do it and the notification is sent instantly.

You can find more information on how to integrate Batch with Firebase here:

https://batch.com/parse-replacement-with-firebase

Comment: Good solution. But just to be clear: this does require you to run a node.js script on a server, right? Or are you pushing directly from the client app?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In my case a notification is based on a slightly more complicated event. Under the hood I have a queue of events stored in Firebase database for which notifications have to be send. Client apps are pushing to this queue when a certain event appears and my node.js script is observing the queue and consuming events from it one by one. For one such event it sends a notification related to this event using Batch REST api. An example entry in the queue stores Firebase user id which is used by Batch to identify the recipient and additional data such as payload, event type and so on

Comment: Yeah. That queue based approach is the one that most Firebase devs use and it comes highly recommended (it's essentially pattern 2 in this classic [blog post on app architectures with Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-25-where-does-firebase-fit.html)). I was just wondering if you were able to (securely) push from device directly to another device through Batch. I wouldn't know how btw, so it was purely curiosity.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Batch REST api, which have to be used if you want to push for a device using a custom identifier (Firebase user id in this case), requires putting your REST Key in a request, so at least for me pushing from that way from a client app doesn't seem like a good idea. Are you thinking about some other methods of achieving that?

Comment: Nope, that's pretty much what I expected. I just hoped someone found a way to securely allow this device-to-device communication, but wouldn't know a way either.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion, you two. I have zero experience with node.js, so I better get learning. That seems like a good solution for me if I can get it working, though.

Comment: @jakhamma node.js is no magic at all. If you are into programming and seen javascript somewhere in the past you can put the working code for this in no time at all, so don't worry :)

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of notification and when to send it's depends on you and your server side script. write server like this with some logic that it's send notification where needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a general thought because there's not enough info in the question to provide a specific answer:

I would suggest leveraging the built-in power of Firebase instead of working around it with a push.

Firebase events are instant and live and provide a wealth of information, it doesn't require a separate server or host to handle them.

A quick example

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Picard"
  uid_1
    name: "Riker"
```

and the games & turns node

```
games
  game_id_1701
    players
       uid_0: true
       uid_1: true
    turns
      turn_id_0
        player_id: uid_0
        event: "powered up weapons"
      turn_id_1
        player_id: uid_1
        event: "engaged shields"
      turn_id_2
        player_id: uid_0
        event: "fired photon torpedoes"
      turn_id_3
        player_id: uid_1
        event: "shield impact, shields at 80%"
```

So with this structure a player logs in and can query all games they are part of, in this case player uid_0 and uid_1 are playing game # 1701

Once they establish which games they are part of, they can observe the turns node of that game. The turns node will provide the user with what has happened so far; turn #, events etc.

Then any future events, like when uid_0 takes turn_id_4 and fires phasers, will notify uid_1 of that event.

There are dozens of different ways to set this up, for example

```
completed_turns
  uid_0: true
  uid_1: false
```

In this super simple example both uid_0 and uid_1 observe the completed_turns node and when they complete their turn, set their respective child to true, and change the other to false. The other player would be notified of that event and can take their turn.